# Angularjs - Inject factory without reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have the following code:

main.js

```
angular.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.name = "Bob";
}
```

myservices.js

```
angular.factory('myService', function($http) {

  var myService = {
    async: function(params) {
      // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
      var promise = $http.get("http://myws/user/info/"+params).then(function (response) {
        // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
        console.log(response);
        // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
        return response.data;
      });
      // Return the promise to the controller
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return myService;
});
```

How can inject `myService` in `myCtrl` ? considering they are in two separated files.

Comment: what difference it makes if these are in in separate files.
Just inject service as you are injecting scope and rootscope. Make sure your service.js is included in webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add in order all of our scripts we have created to run this angular, take note the order:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="myservices.js"></script>
```

`main.js` should look like:

```
var app = angular.module("MyModule", []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, myService) { /* implementation */})
```

`services.js` should look like:

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) { /* implementation */});
```

So in our `main.js` we are creating a module to attach all of our services, factories, providers, values, constants, controllers and directives. It also allows us to put the config and run phase functions in.

The module is instantiated via:

`angular.module("MyModule", []);`

We're providing a second argument of other dependant modules

If we needed to, we could ask angular for the module again, in the case of use javascript modules:

`var app = angular.module("MyModule");`

Comment: get rid of using `var app`. You are redeclaring same variable

Answer (score 1):

Below are several thing you need to do.

1. Should be they should belong same/different angular `module`(if its different module then you have inject into main module to use it).
2. You need to use `angular.module('myApp')` to bind components to it, so that the service will be available in that module.

**Code**

```
//app.js
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.service']); //this should be module definition somewhere

//service.js
angular.module('myApp.service', [])
angular.module('myApp.service').factory('myService', function($http) {
     //service code
});

//controller.js
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, myService) {
    console.log(myService); //service instance here
    $scope.name = "Bob";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the files are both actually loaded. How to do that is up to you, perhaps you're using some implementation of `require()`, or you simply list all the files in your HTML as `<script>` tags.
2. Clarify what module structure you want to have. Should both be part of the same module, or should they be separate modules?

   - Same module: One file needs to declare the module, the other needs to extend it:

     ```
     angular.module('Foo', [])  // declares new module
         .controller(..)

     angular.module('Foo')      // extends existing module
         .factory(..)
     ```
   - Different modules:

     ```
     angular.module('Foo', [])  // declares new module
         .factory(..)

     angular.module('Bar', ['Foo'])  // declares new module
         .controller(..)             // and imports other module
     ```
3. Inject into the controller:

   ```
   .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, myService) ..
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you can inject service in your controller

like:

main.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', ['$scope', 'myService',
    function ($scope, myService) {

    }
]);
```

myService.js:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', function($http) {
     //service code
});
```

for different file but same module then ensure that file is loaded before use.